# How to wrap Datamapper to_json response in a object-key hash

Tags: json, sinatra, ruby-datamapper, to-json

I'm working with a json parser that requires my response to be wrapped in an object-key hash.  When I use DataMapper's .to_json method(datamapper/dm-serializer) the repsone I get is correct

```
get '/plane/all' do
  @plane = Plane.all(:order => :id.desc).to_json(:relationships => {:pilots => {}, :passengers => {}, :cabin => {}})
  @plane
end
```

The response in JSON

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Plane 2","picture_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com","pilots":[{"pilot_id":2,"header":"Bruce Wayne","details":"Bruce loves his batwing that flies at an average speed of 200 mph","picture_url":"www.marvel.com","plane_id":2}],"passengers":[{"passenger_id":2,"name":"Passenger 2","details":"These are the details for passenger 2","picture_url":"www.toobar.com/","plane_id":2}],"cabin":[{"cabin_id":2,"details":"Great Details for has been put in this cabin","picture_url":"www.seatingchart.com","video_link":"www.skyview.com","passenger_passenger_id":2}]},{"id":1,"name":"Plane 1","picture_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com","pilots":[{"pilot_id":1,"header":"Jack Smith","details":"Jack Smith description","picture_url":"https://www.foobar.com","plane_id":1}],"passengers":[{"passenger_id":1,"name":"Passenger 1","details":"Passenger 1 details","picture_url":"www.toobar.com/","passenger_id":1}],"cabin":[{"cabin_id":1,"details":"Flight details","picture_url":"www.seatingchart.com","video_link":"www.skyview.com","passenger_passenger_id":1}]}]
```

To wrap this response as a key I used the 'json' gem which has it's own to_json method

```
get '/plane/all' do
  @plane = Plane.all(:order => :id.desc).to_json(:relationships => {:pilots => {}, :passengers => {}, :cabin => {}})
 { "planes" => @plane }.to_json
end
```

Here is the response

```
{"planes":"[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Plane 2\",\"picture_url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com\",\"pilots\":[{\"pilot_id\":2,\"header\":\"Bruce Wayne\",\"details\":\"Bruce loves his batwing that flies at an average speed of 200 mph\",\"picture_url\":\"www.marvel.com\",\"plane_id\":2}],\"passengers\":[{\"passenger_id\":2,\"name\":\"Passenger 2\",\"details\":\"These are the details for passenger 2\",\"picture_url\":\"www.toobar.com/\",\"plane_id\":2}],\"cabin\":[{\"cabin_id\":2,\"details\":\"Great Details for has been put in this cabin\",\"picture_url\":\"www.seatingchart.com\",\"video_link\":\"www.skyview.com\",\"passenger_passenger_id\":2}]},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Plane 1\",\"picture_url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com\",\"pilots\":[{\"pilot_id\":1,\"header\":\"Jack Smith\",\"details\":\"Jack Smith description\",\"picture_url\":\"https://www.foobar.com\",\"plane_id\":1}],\"passengers\":[{\"passenger_id\":1,\"name\":\"Passenger 1\",\"details\":\"Passenger 1 details\",\"picture_url\":\"www.toobar.com/\",\"plane_id\":1}],\"cabin\":[{\"cabin_id\":1,\"details\":\"Flight details\",\"picture_url\":\"www.seatingchart.com\",\"video_link\":\"www.skyview.com\",\"passenger_passenger_id\":1}]}]"}
```

Long story short, the JSON response I get has backslashes in it and JSON parser I'm using states it's only one object instead of the two I had previously.

Anyone who can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround. If there is no view, then no need to use an instance variable.

```
def '/plane/all' do
    planes = Plane.all(:order => :id.desc).to_json(:relationships => {:pilots => {}, :passengers => {}, :cabin => {}})
    { "planes" => JSON.parse(planes) }.to_json
end
```